# Voice recognition in J2ME

Tags: java-me, mobile, speech-recognition, speech

I'm developing a mobile application using j2me. There I need to have a speech recognition function, so that application should be able to process and act upon the commands given by the user. What I wanted to know is

1. Is this technically possible (I'm a novice to j2me programming)?
2. If it is possible, where can I find a j2me library for speech recognition?

Thanks in advance,

Nuwan

Answer (score 3):

1. This is technically possible, but in
   reality most devices that run J2ME
   aren't powerful enough to do it in pure Java code. You need to look for devices which support JSR 113 - JavaTM Speech API 2.0.
2. Look at [JSR 113 - JavaTM Speech API 2.0](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=113).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think using JSR 113 will limit the type of devices that I can use the system very badly. 
What if I record the voice from the mobile and send the audio file to the server and do the voice recognition processing there and send the result back to the mobile. Will that be a better approach?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the better approach. There will be a bit of a delay while you send the data, and users may also object to the data charges (e.g. I pay £1/Mb on my calling plan.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java Speech API Implementation (JSR-113), which supposed to do [speech recognition](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-guide/Recognition.html):

But, unfortunately, I don't know if any device support it :)

If you want to implement speech recognition yourself, there are many limitations in j2me such as slow performance, and impossibility to access audio data while recording.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, due to slow performance I'm also thinking about doing the recognition part in the server. But still I couldn't figure out which is the better approach

Comment: Yes, I think that it is better to record audio-clip in mobile application, send it to server and recognize it using some powerful recognition system.

Answer (score 1):

An in-between way may be to do very simple ASR in the client (e.g. yes,no,digits etc) and for anything beyond you can send it to the server.  The limits on what the client can do can change in the future in you upgrade your phone.